# how to pass an object in nativescript-dropdown & get the selected index & display the value?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to use dropdown in nativescript-angular. So for that i've added the plugin nativescript-drop-down.[link](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-drop-down/)
But i'm facing problems in case of sending objects as items & customise the items & get the value,index! In this plugin, i can't even change the background color of selected item in dropdown.

Is there any better way to use dropdown in nativescript-angular or how can i implement objects through this plugin?

Comment: Can you show the code you already have ready? It might be easier then to show where the fault is.